# How to set the Proxy server in code for a RestClient API

Tags: vb.net, rest

I have an REST API that needs to communicate with a BMC (Remedy) server in our network. My code runs on a Windows server that already has an API for a different reason running and it uses the proxy server you can set up via IE. However this new API will not run using that proxy server. I know this new code works because when I change the proxy server in IE to the one it likes, my code runs fine. But, the other API stops working.

What I need to do is find a way in code to change the proxy server for this one particular API uses. While not messing with the other one set in IE.

This is part of code (vb.net) where I believe I need to add some statements to use a different proxy server. I have searched all over the Internet and found all kinds of ways to do this but none seem to work. Hoping someone can tell me what statements I need to add get this done.

```
         Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient(strUri)
         Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
         request.AddHeader("Connection", "close")
         request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache,no-cache")
         request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
         request.AddParameter("undefined", strUserIdPassword, ParameterType.RequestBody)
         request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*")
         Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
         strToken = response.Content
```

Comment: RestClient has a `Proxy` property (standard IWebProxy). Are you using .Net Core? (Assuming RestSharp 106+)

Comment: Using .net framework 4.7.2 and  using RestSharp

Comment: Then you can set `client.Proxy = new WebProxy("Some address", [some port])`

Comment: Does not seem to like ("Proxyaddress", [80]) suspect I have they syntax wrong.. would it be ("Proxyaddress:80")

Comment: I assume it doesn't. Maybe something like `new WebProxy("10.1.1.254", 8080)` fits better (`[...]` means *some value*). I have no knowledge of your LAN. -- Does it need credentials? Does it use default credentials (in the CredentialCache)? Do you need to pre-authenticate? (don't answer back, this is stuff *you* know).

Comment: Started up Wireshark and it looks like I am getting out to the d/e now with that statement added. But I am getting back 405 Method not allowed. So, I guess I have a new problem... lol... But, I at least I am a step closer!

Comment: Going to close this one out as I am able to get the call to a specific API working. The command for the dotnet program is - client. proxy = new WebProxy("YourProxyAddressHere") Thanks to Jimi for the help!

Comment: To *close it*, post the answer yourself, explaining what you have done that solves what problem and then accept it, as soon as you're allowed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able to get the call to a specific API working. The command for the dotnet program is:

```cs
client.proxy = new WebProxy("YourProxyAddressHere")
```

Credit to Jimi, [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975329/how-to-set-the-proxy-server-in-code-for-a-restclient-api/69005047#comment121902841_68975329).